# Facebook REST API for links.getStats alternative needed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rest

I am building a site where I need the social sharing statistics of a particular URL for example http://www.facebook.com/.

So I came across this REST api by facebook which solves the problem perfectly.

https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://www.facebook.com/

But I noticed that the API will be deprecated , and I have no idea when.

I wanted to know what is the Facebook Graph API alternatice to the same legacy REST API.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `link_stat` FQL table - this has the same information.
You can also use the Insights API on Graph API depending on what metrics you need

Comment: This is just perfect ! Thanks ! 
More about link_stat at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/

Comment: When I answered this 4 years ago the answer was correct (`link_stat` in FQL) and also mentioned some alternatives briefly. 

If you're looking at this now because FQL was removed, you're probably looking for this document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/url